# Android toolbar context menu for listview items

Tags: android, android-listview, menu, contextmenu, android-toolbar

I am looking for help on how to implement a context menu in the toolbar for ListView items, like WhatsApp does it. The only tutorials I found so far are about a dialog that pops up, which is not what I want. Can someone help me or provide links with tutorials? Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this official android guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

**EDIT:**

**Using the contextual action mode**

For views that provide contextual actions, you should usually invoke the contextual action mode upon one of two events (or both):

- The user performs a long-click on the view.
- The user selects a checkbox or similar UI component within the
  view.

How your application invokes the contextual action mode and defines the behavior for each action depends on your design. There are basically two designs:

- For contextual actions on individual, arbitrary views.
- For batch contextual actions on groups of items in a ListView or
  GridView (allowing the user to select multiple items and perform an
  action on them all).

**Enabling the contextual action mode for individual views**

1. Implement the ActionMode.Callback interface. In its callback methods, you can specify the actions for the contextual action bar, respond to click events on action items, and handle other lifecycle events for the action mode.

   ```
   private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new             ActionMode.Callback() {

   // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
       // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
       MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
       return true;
   }

   // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
   // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
       return false; // Return false if nothing is done
   }

   // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
   @Override
   public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.menu_share:
               shareCurrentItem();
               mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
               return true;
           default:
               return false;
       }
   }

   // Called when the user exits the action mode
   @Override
   public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
       mActionMode = null;
   }
   };
   ```
2. Call startActionMode() when you want to show the bar (such as when the user long-clicks the view).

   ```
   someView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
   // Called when the user long-clicks on someView
   public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
       if (mActionMode != null) {
           return false;
       }

       // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
       mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
       view.setSelected(true);
       return true;
   }
   });
   ```

**Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView**

If you have a collection of items in a ListView or GridView (or another extension of AbsListView) and want to allow users to perform batch actions, you should:

- Implement the AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener interface and set
  it for the view group with setMultiChoiceModeListener(). In the
  listener's callback methods, you can specify the actions for the
  contextual action bar, respond to click events on action items, and
  handle other callbacks inherited from the ActionMode.Callback
  interface.
- Call setChoiceMode() with the CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL argument.

  ```
  ListView listView = getListView();
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
  listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                        long id, boolean checked) {
      // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
      // such as update the title in the CAB
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
      // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.menu_delete:
              deleteSelectedItems();
              mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
              return true;
          default:
              return false;
      }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu for the CAB
      MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
      // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
      // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
      // an invalidate() request
      return false;
  }
  });
  ```

For more menu features [check this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Taifun thx for help with improving my answer. Hope I did it right.